# Generating wildcard SSL certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate

I can make a single SSL certificate for several different domain names:

```
www1.example.com
www2.example.com
www3.example.com
```

But `*.example.com` doesn't work.

How can I make a single SSL certificate for all sub domains within `.example.com`?

---

P.S. Here is the extension part of the generated certificate:

```
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
            CA:FALSE
        X509v3 Key Usage: 
            Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment
        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
            DNS:*.example.com
```

It's simply not matched by any sub-domain under `example.com` by the browser.

Comment: what are you using to make these certs?

Comment: I'm using openssl 1.0.1c.

Comment: How does it not work? Does the certificate generation fail? Does it succeed but the client reports a name mismatch? What is the error message?

Comment: Well, I can generate the certificate with `*` char in the domain name, but it's not matched.

Comment: That should work, but try setting `*.example.com` as the Common Name.

Comment: Oh, I don't know what happened, but it works now! @mgorven It don't have to be the Common Name, still I put the wildcards in the DNS field, and it just worked now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit old but I am sure this process has not changed that much over the years

> mkdir /usr/share/ssl/certs/hostname.domain.com
>   cd /usr/share/ssl/certs/hostname.domain.com
>   (umask 077 && touch host.key host.cert host.info host.pem)
>   openssl genrsa 2048 > host.key
>   openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha1 -days 3650 -key host.key > host.cert
>   ...[enter *.domain.com for the Common Name]...
>   openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -text < host.cert > host.info
>   cat host.cert host.key > host.pem
>   chmod 400 host.key host.pem

http://www.justinsamuel.com/2006/03/11/howto-create-a-self-signed-wildcard-ssl-certificate/

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.